# Angularjs data binding issue / javascript being weird

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is undoubtedly a stupid problem where I'm just doing something simple wrong.

I have a page with several directives, loading their templates and controllers. All of which is working fine except for this one.

Using the controller as model, `this.` is the same as `$scope.`. So in my controller I have:

```
var self = this;
this.states = { showControls: false, showVideo: false }

this.showVideo = function() { self.states.showVideo = true; }
this.showControls = function() { self.states.showControls = true; }

$scope.$on(Constants.EVENT.START_WEBCAM, self.showVideo)
$scope.$on(Constants.EVENT.VIDEO_SUCCESS, self.showControls)
```

In the view I have a button to reveal this part of the view and subsequently request access to your webcam. Clicking the button broadcasts an event with `$rootScope.$broadcast` from the parent controller.

When the user grants access to the webcam (handled in the directive's link function) it broadcasts another event the same way.

Both methods are triggered by listening with `$scope.$on`, and both methods fire as they should. However, the showVideo method successfully updates its associated state property, and the showControls method does not. What am I doing wrong?

Using the debug tool it *looks* like `states.showControls` is being set to true, but this change isn't reflected in the view, and adding a watcher to the states object doesn't detect any change at this point either. It does when I set `showVideo`.

**EDIT**
This part is in the directive:

```
  if (Modernizr && Modernizr.prefixed('getUserMedia', navigator)) {
    userMedia = Modernizr.prefixed('getUserMedia', navigator);
  }

  var videoSuccess = function(stream) { 
  // Do some stuff
  $rootScope.$broadcast(Constants.EVENT.VIDEO_SUCCESS);

  }

  scope.$on(Constants.EVENT.START_WEBCAM, function() {
    if (MediaStreamTrack && MediaStreamTrack.getSources) {

      MediaStreamTrack.getSources(function(sourceInfo) {
        var audio = null;
        var video = null;

        _.each(sourceInfo, function(info, i) {
          if (info.kind === "audio") {
            audio = info.id;
          } else if (info.kind === "video") {
            video = info.id;
          } else {
            console.log("random unknown source: ", info);
          }
        });

        if (userMedia) { userMedia(getReqs(), videoSuccess, error); }

      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: You arent showing the more relevant part which triggers the event.

Comment: $rootScope.$broadcast(Constants.EVENT.START_WEBCAM);
$rootScope.$broadcast(Constants.EVENT.VIDEO_SUCCESS);

Comment: Ofcourse that is evident, but when is it happening, you would need to show more code especially `When the user grants access to the webcam`? How? if it is an action that happens outside angular context you would need to manually apply the digest cycle.

Comment: Sorry, I added the relevant parts from the directive that are triggering it all.

Comment: You would need to call `$rootScope.$apply()` right after `$rootScope.$broadcast(Constants.EVENT.VIDEO_SUCCESS);` use apply or applyAsync

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize I needed to trigger apply again. I thought having a watcher on the variable, then changing it, should do that. But I guess since the watcher isn't firing, that makes perfect sense.